# How to implement one stored proc in SSRS for Security?

Tags: security, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I developed 65 SSRS 2008 reports and now I want to add a layer of security.  For the security, I created a stored proc that selects the user's windows ID as a parameter and returns a list of all clients in the database that they should have access to.  Then, my main stored proc joins this list of clients to filter all matching records that the user has access to.

I added the logic from the security stored proc to the main stored proc and it works successfully.  But my boss wants me to instead set up security so that each RDL file links to this one security stored proc.  This way we only have to change the security logic in one stored proc, rather than changing 65 sprocs.  So I want to remove the security logic from the main sproc and instead add the security sproc for each report.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using integrated security, you would be much better served by creating a view that uses [SUSER_SNAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) to filter the appropriate clients. Join to this view in all of your stored procedures. Thus, the view becomes the security filter, and you don't have to mess around in 65 SSRS reports, which, IMO, is way more of a maintenance nightmare than doing things on the back-end.